# Are there locations in a residence where a non tamper resistant receptacle can still be used?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Assume for a second that my jurisdiction has adopted 2011 NEC code as legally binding without significant amendment. This code requires (406.11) that 120V 15/20A outlets in all areas defined in NEC 210.52 must be tamper-resistant, and that existing grandfathered outlets are only grandfathered until replaced; any replacement must be TR. Exceptions are:

- Outlets more than 5.5' off the ground (only common one I can think of is the one for a garage door opener)
- Outlets designed to be used by a major appliance which normally blocks access to the receptacle (mostly in the kitchen; fridge/stove/oven/dishwasher)
- Outlets built in to light fixtures or lumieres (and so replacing them would involve replacing the entire light fixture which may be expensive or impossible)

210.52 covers pretty much any outlet in an interior space of a residential building, including attached garages. It doesn't specifically cover closets but the NEC doesn't treat closets any differently than the interior space containing the closet. It also doesn't (AFAIK) cover attic spaces that haven't been finished. I don't have a basement so don't worry about that.

All that being said, **is there any outlet in my house, besides the one for the fridge (ex 2), stove (ditto) and garage door opener (ex 1 - on the ceiling), that wouldn't be required to be TR if/when I replace it?**

This also begs the (somewhat argumentative) question of why standard (non-TR) outlets are still sold to "amateur" electricians. At least in my area, they are only code-compliant in commercial spaces that aren't healthcare, child care or hotel spaces (ask the next 100 people who buy an outlet where they plan to install it, and 99 will say "in my home"), and in VERY LIMITED circumstances in residential, where a TR outlet would also be just fine. I'm not sure exactly how the store would be expected to tell who would install it in a compliant way, but it seems disingenuous for a store to sell 10-packs of outlets that would be illegal to install without at least having the POS system throw up a flag at checkout (like they already do for age-restricted items like glues/paints/solvents).

Comment: It's not the responsibility of the store to enforce codes, that's the Electrical Inspectors job (which is likely unionized, so he'd file a grievance if the stores did his job).

Comment: @tester101: Funny. But actually, there are a lot of laws regarding possession of certain items, which retail stores are expected to help enforce at point of sale. Alcohol, ciggs, VOC products which can be inhaled, firearms and firearm-like devices such as pellet and paintball guns, etc etc. However, that wasn't the main question.

Comment: If the vast majority of the outlets are required to be TR, why worry about which ones don't need to be? Just install them everywhere and be done with it.

Comment: @Steven: That's a pretty big retrofit in my case. Theoretically I agree, but I don't have long until my daughter is going to start crawling, so I'm working in three phases; ones that need replacing before she can move around on her own (and we let her do so in certain living areas), ones that need replacing before she has the run of the house, and ones that aren't going to be a concern because she can't possibly reach them before we can teach her the danger.

Comment: This question really identifies that third category; if it's not required by NEC it's because it's extremely unlikely for a preschooler to get to them, or simply impractical to replace them.

Comment: @KeithS Save yourself some cash and pick up some [Outlet Plugs](http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=12011319). NEC only requires tamper resistant receptacles in new installs and when receptacles are replaced.  We all grew up with open receptacles, and most of us made it.

Comment: My niece is two, and can remove most outlet plugs in nothing flat. And conversely there are child-safe plugs in her parents' house which even the parents can't get back out. Yes, I'm probably being overcautious, but my daughter is incredibly cute so you'll just have to forgive me.

Comment: No safety device has ever been invented that can match the vigilant parent.

Comment: I applaud better safety regulations, but I recently installed many outlets in my unfinished basement and It just didnt make sense to put in TR ones there.

Comment: -1 :   I am downvoting because your question is literally its own answer.   Why not just remove all the preamble and answer the question yourself?

Comment: I was just looking at another related question last night.  It doesn't appear the tamper resistant outlets are worth the cost and hassle.  They don't seem to have a significant impact on child safety.  Maybe the home improvement stores are thinking with their head?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While Article **406.11 Tamper-Resistant Receptacles in Dwelling Units.** existed in NEC 2008, it was revised as Article **406.12 Tamper-Resistant Receptacles in Dwelling Units.** in NEC 2011. And it says Tamper-Resistant Receptacles are required in all areas listed in Article 210.52

> ## National Electrical Code 2011
>
> ### ARTICLE 210 Branch Circuits
>
> **210.52 Dwelling Unit Receptacle Outlets.**
> **(A) General Provisions.**
>
> - kitchen
> - family room
> - dining room
> - living room
> - parlor
> - library
> - den
> - sunroom
> - bedroom
> - recreation room
> - or similar room or area of dwelling units
>
> (B) Small Appliances
>
> (C) Countertops
>
> (D) Bathrooms
>
> (E) Outdoor Outlets
>
> (F) Laundry Areas
>
> (G) Basements and Garages
>
> (H) Hallways

With the following exceptions.

> *Ex.: Receptacles in the following locations aren’t required to be tamper-resistant:*
>
> *(1) Receptacles located more than 5½ ft above the floor.*
> *(2) Receptacles that are part of a luminaire or appliance.*
> *(3) A receptacle located within dedicated space for an appliance that in normal use isn’t easily moved from one place to another.*
> *(4) Nongrounding receptacles used for replacements as permitted in 406.4(D)(2)(a).*

Comment: This answer doesn't really tell me anything I didn't already know as of when I wrote the OP. I think I can add two more outlets to my list; the ones for the washer and dryer, as they are located behind said appliances which definitely qualify as "not easily moved". I have no non-grounded plugs; the house was built in the late 70s so 110v outlets had to be grounded. So, I think by this answer that you agree that every plug in a typical SFD that isn't for the fridge, stove, GDO, or W/D must be at least TR, and outdoor/wet areas must be WR.

Comment: Tester, Can you send me the link you use for NEC???  thanks

Comment: @shirlockhomes No link. my source is not online. It'll cost you $90.00. [NFPA 70 :National Electrical Code](http://www.nfpa.org/catalog/product.asp?pid=7011SB&icid=B484)

Comment: Follow-up Q. Does an attic space that isn't finished as living space count as "outdoor"? If finished, it's definitely a living space and so outlets must be TR, but if not, it doesn't really fall into any other listed area that would require TR, unless it's considered outdoor space.

Comment: @KeithS not outdoor (unless you don't have a roof, or only have 3 walls). If it has a floor (not just joists) and a non-movable staircase leading to it, I might call it living space. Maybe "Storage or Equipment Spaces."

Comment: Some of it is floored in plywood. They're all "crawl spaces", and none have a built-in ladder or staircase.

Comment: Then I'd call it Storage, in which case the only requirement would be one lighting outlet (*outlet* not receptacle) controlled by a switch at the normal point of entry. Since this area is not covered in 210.52, receptacles are not required in this area and so tamper resistant receptacles are not required either.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, there IS a copy of the 2011 NEC available for free. http://www.nfpa.org/aboutthecodes/AboutTheCodes.asp?DocNum=70&cookie_test=1 You have to sign into their site (it's free to register), and the online version has some severe limitations (single-page scrolling, no search, save or print), but it's there.

Comment: So, looks like an outlet behind a wall mounted TV would fall into exception 3. Reason being that there is a recessed black non-TR outlet I'd like to install behind my TV

Comment: @Tester101: One thing I'm not clear on: does this section demand replacing existing outlets in those locations (including GFCI?) or is it just new work?

Comment: @keshlam just new, permitted work. Unless some type of other laws/codes require you to bring things up to current code.

Comment: @keshlam existing work is generally grandfathered in (check codes in your jurisdiction) _unless_ it constitutes a safety hazard. My house built a few decades ago has many violations of modern building and electrical code, but is in no danger of falling over or bursting into flames. For example: certain configurations of knob and tube wiring might be considered a hazard because it can burn your house down, while non-TR outlets probably would not.

Answer (score -1):

The TR rule applies whether you get a permit or not.  I install TR in every receptacle location. They cost about 60 cents more than the baby killer open outlets. IMO open outlets should not be sold anywhere.

Comment: If you're concerned about the safety of babies in your house, you'd be better to install combination afi/gfi breakers for all your receptacle and lighting circuits.

Comment: While your _opinion_ is valid, it's irrelevant when it comes to what the code says and what's legal. In _my_ opinion, most posted speed limits are far too low, but that won't matter if a cop pulls me over. If you'd care to [edit] this into an answer to the question asked, please do so, otherwise, it will likely be deleted soon. If you'll spend a moment taking the [tour], you'll understand why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).